# Как вызвать диалоговое окно выбора папки на Python с помощью модуля PyQt5?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui, qfiledialog, getexistingdirectory

Я учился делать десктопные приложения с помощью модуля tkinter. В tkinter можно очень просто вызвать окно выбора папки, это я легко нашел в гугле.

Но вот для *PyQt5* такое я найти не смог. 
Пожалуйста, подскажите, как можно вызвать окно выбора папки с помощью модуля PyQt5?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Класс `QFileDialog` предоставляет диалог, позволяющий пользователям выбирать файлы или каталоги.

> [static]QString QFileDialog::getExistingDirectory(QWidget *parent = nullptr, const QString &caption = QString(), const QString &dir = QString(), QFileDialog::Options options = ShowDirsOnly)
>
> Это удобная статическая функция, которая возвращает существующий каталог, выбранный пользователем.

```
import sys
import os
from PyQt5.QtGui     import *
from PyQt5.QtCore    import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *


class Form(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self,parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        
        self.plainTextEdit = QPlainTextEdit()
        self.plainTextEdit.setFont(QFont('Arial', 11))

        openDirButton = QPushButton("Open Directory")
        openDirButton.clicked.connect(self.getDirectory)

        getFileNameButton = QPushButton("Open File")
        getFileNameButton.clicked.connect(self.getFileName)

        getFileNamesButton = QPushButton("Open Files")
        getFileNamesButton.clicked.connect(self.getFileNames)

        saveFileNameButton = QPushButton("Save File")
        saveFileNameButton.clicked.connect(self.saveFile)

        layoutV = QVBoxLayout()
        layoutV.addWidget(openDirButton)
        layoutV.addWidget(getFileNameButton)
        layoutV.addWidget(getFileNamesButton)
        layoutV.addWidget(saveFileNameButton)
        
        layoutH = QHBoxLayout()
        layoutH.addLayout(layoutV)
        layoutH.addWidget(self.plainTextEdit)

        centerWidget = QWidget()
        centerWidget.setLayout(layoutH) 
        self.setCentralWidget(centerWidget)
        
        self.resize(740,480)
        self.setWindowTitle("PyQt5-QFileDialog")

    def getDirectory(self):                                                     # <-----
        dirlist = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self,"Выбрать папку",".")
        self.plainTextEdit.appendHtml("<br>Выбрали папку: <b>{}</b>".format(dirlist))

    def getFileName(self):
        filename, filetype = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self,
                             "Выбрать файл",
                             ".",
                             "Text Files(*.txt);;JPEG Files(*.jpeg);;\
                             PNG Files(*.png);;GIF File(*.gif);;All Files(*)")
        self.plainTextEdit.appendHtml("<br>Выбрали файл: <b>{}</b> <br> <b>{:*^54}</b>"
                                      "".format(filename, filetype))

    def getFileNames(self):
        filenames, ok = QFileDialog.getOpenFileNames(self,
                             "Выберите несколько файлов",
                             ".",
                             "All Files(*.*)")
        self.plainTextEdit.appendHtml("""<br>Выбрали несколько файлов: 
                                       <b>{}</b> <br> <b>{:*^80}</b>"""
                                      "".format(filenames, ok))
       
        folder = os.path.dirname(filenames[0])                                        
        print("folder =", folder)        
        self.plainTextEdit.appendHtml("""<br>пути файлов, которые я выбираю: 
                                       <b>{}</b> """
                                      "".format(folder))        

    def saveFile(self):
        filename, ok = QFileDialog.getSaveFileName(self,
                             "Сохранить файл",
                             ".",
                             "All Files(*.*)")
        self.plainTextEdit.appendHtml("<br>Сохранить файл: <b>{}</b> <br> <b>{:*^54}</b>"
                                      "".format(filename, ok))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = Form()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Огромное спасибо!

Comment: Не подскажете, почему pylint в VSCode ругается(отмечает ошибкой) многие ключевые фразы,такие как QMainWindow, QPlainTextEdit, QFont, QPushButton и другие? Я могу как-то поправить это? Немного мешает просмотру кода и не дает сконцентрироваться на реальных ошибках

Comment: @MAXIM045 я с `VSCode` не работал. Попробуйте задать новый вопрос, укажите нужные метки `vscode` и `pyqt5`, думаю вам помогут.