# Есть ли в python функция, возвращающая абсолютный путь к папке?

Tags: python, pyqt5, gui

Пытаюсь реализовать выбор папки, для сохранения файла, обработанного моей программой. Для поиска файла использовал

```
fd.askopenfilename()
    def callbackOpen(self):
        self.name = fd.askopenfilename()
        self.compressor.set_path(self.name)
        print(self.name)
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1074054/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d0%b5-%d0%be%d0%ba%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-python-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b4%d1%83%d0%bb%d1%8f-pyqt5/1074082#1074082 , https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1120843/%d0%92%d1%8b%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-qfiledialog/1120906#1120906 ?

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
print(os.path.abspath(*))
```

Измените `*` на путь к папке